# listview items are getting double automatically when i run the code

Tags: android, arrays, listview, fragment, textwatcher

i am using text-watcher and displaying result in list-view and items of list view through string array using string resources i don't know my my list get automatically double when i searched any items in it 
please help

```
public class HingDict extends Fragment {
    ListView list;
    ListViewAdapter adapter;
    EditText editsearch;

    Resources res;
    ArrayList<Dictionary> arraylist = new ArrayList<Dictionary>();

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.hingdict,container,false);

        res=getResources();
        String hinglish[]=res.getStringArray(R.array.hinglish);
        String english[]=res.getStringArray(R.array.english);


        list = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listview);

        for (int i = 0; i < hinglish.length; i++) 
        {
            Dictionary dc = new Dictionary(hinglish[i],
                    english[i]);

            arraylist.add(dc);
        }

        adapter = new ListViewAdapter(getActivity(), arraylist);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        editsearch = (EditText)view. findViewById(R.id.search);


        editsearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String text = editsearch.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
                adapter.filter(text);
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                    int arg2, int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
     return view;
    }


}
```

Comment: what is `ListViewAdapter` in "adapter = new ListViewAdapter(..." ?

Comment: clear the arraylist before adding new results
if(arraylist.size() >0){
arraylist.clear();
}
 arraylist.add(dc);

Comment: ListViewAdapter is a class used for handling listview

Comment: public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
 Context mContext;
 LayoutInflater inflater;
 private List<Dictionary> dictionarylist = null;
 private ArrayList<Dictionary> arraylist;
 
 public ListViewAdapter(Context context, List<Dictionary> dictionarylist) {
  mContext = context;
  this.dictionarylist = dictionarylist;
  inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
  this.arraylist = new ArrayList<Dictionary>();
  this.arraylist.addAll(dictionarylist);
 }

Comment: where i need to implement that code  if(arraylist.size() >0){ arraylist.clear(); } arraylist.add(dc); in mainactivty at the time of calling textwatcher or in the listviewadapter class